# How to square crop a cameraImage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, widget, crop

I'm creating a scanner and I needed to implement a square overlay to the Camera preview, I take the image stream from the Camera Preview and send it to an API, now after adding the square overlay I need to square crop the cameraImage taken from the Camera preview before sending it to the API.

I only have the cameraImage -which is **YUV** 420 format- taken how can I crop it programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that for the full image you coded something like that:

```dart
Uint8List getBytes() {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in cameraImage.planes) {
        allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

In fact, you are concatenating one after the other the data of the 3 planes of YUV: all Y, then all U, then all V.
As you can see in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion) plane Y has the same width and height as the image, while planes U and V use width/2 and height/2.
If we go byte after byte that means that the code above is similar to the following code:

```
int divider = 1; // for first plane: Y
for (final Plane plane in cameraImage.planes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cameraImage.height ~/ divider; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cameraImage.width ~/ divider; j++) {
            allBytes.putUint8(plane.bytes[j + i * cameraImage.width ~/ divider]);
        }
    }
    divider = 2; // for planes U and V
}
```

Now that you're here, I think you understand how to crop:

```
int divider = 1; // for first plane: Y
for (final Plane plane in cameraImage.planes) {
  for (int i = cropTop ~/ divider; i < cropBottom ~/ divider; i++) {
    for (int j = cropLeft ~/ divider; j < cropRight ~/ divider; j++) {
      allBytes.putUint8(plane.bytes[j + i * cameraImage.width ~/ divider]);
    }
  }
  divider = 2; // for planes U and V
}
```

where the crop* variables are computed from the full image.

That's the theory: this piece of code does not take into consideration the camera orientation, the possible side-effects with odd sizes and the performances. But that's the general idea.